# Integrals with infinite bounds sometimes written as limits, sometimes not?

Tags: integration, notation, infinity

When I saw Wikipedia's notation for the inverse Laplace transform, I became curious if there was a reason behind it.

Is there a reason why [Wikipedia writes the inverse Laplace transform as this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Laplace_transform#Mellin.27s_inverse_formula) $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\lim_{T\to\infty}\int_{\gamma-iT}^{\gamma+iT}e^{st}F(s)\,ds,$$ instead of this?$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty}e^{st}F(s)\,ds,$$

(Is there something wrong with putting an infinity in the bounds?)

Comment: Because the first form has a meaning, while the second doesn't.

Comment: @egreg: Can you explain why? How does infinity not have meaning in the bounds of an integral?

Comment: @Mehrdad do you suggest that $i*\infty$ has a meaning? when adding or multiply something with infnity mostly there's no meaning, while the first form means the expression $\gamma + iT$ when T is bigger as we want

Comment: @DanielY: Yes that's what I'm suggesting. Isn't it exactly the same issue as when we say $\int_{-\infty}^\infty t\,dt$? It's perfectly good notation, it means $\lim_{T \to \infty} \int_{-T}^T t\,dt$ (i.e. we remove the infinity and replace it by a $T$, to take the limit thereof)... why is this case any different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of integrals over the reals, it's common to write
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_a^t f(x)\,dx=\int_a^\infty f(x)\,dx
$$
and similarly for the lower bound. However,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx
$$
means
$$
\lim_{\substack{s\to-\infty\\t\to\infty}}\int_s^t f(x)\,dx
$$
Note that it can happen that this limit doesn't exist, while
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{-t}^t f(x)\,dx
$$
does.

In the case you're showing there's also a different problem: what “path” should be followed for going from $\gamma-i\infty$ to $\gamma+i\infty$? In the complex plane there's no way to define $-\infty$ distinct from $\infty$. I don't want to say that one cannot give a meaning to the notation you're proposing; it's actually not used, because it's too ambiguous.

Comment: Interesting... if you wouldn't mind, could you please show an example of where $\lim_{\substack{s\to-\infty\\t\to\infty}}\int_s^t f(x)\,dx$ doesn't exist but $\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{-t}^t f(x)\,dx$ does? I hadn't realized that's possible before. Also, regarding the "path", isn't it the same kind of "path" (a line) that one would follow if the integral had instead been $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \ldots\,dt$? In that case it would be the real axis, in this case the vertical line at position $\gamma$ -- what other path can exist?

Comment: @Mehrdad $f(x)=\sin x$.

Comment: Oh lol, that makes sense. I don't see why the double-limit is relevant though -- $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \ldots\,dt$ is perfectly validly defined as a single limit, so why is this case different? I don't understand the path thing.

Comment: @Mehrdad In this case you *do* want to use the second interpretation (limit with respect to only one variable). But the main problem is that distinguishing between $-\infty$ and $\infty$ in $\mathbb{C}$ has no sense; one *could* use your notation, why not? Nobody does, though.